# How to combine a property and json response in Laravel + Swagger?

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-php

I have this a project that is using Laravel for the api and swagger for documentation

I have this method in my login controller:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 * 
 * 
 * @OA\Post(
 *     tags={"UnAuthorize"},
 *     path="/login",
 *     summary="User Login",
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *          @OA\MediaType(
 *              mediaType="application/json",
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  type="object",    
 *                  ref="#/components/schemas/LoginRequest",                  
 *              )
 *          )
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *          response="200", 
 *          description="An example resource", 
 *          @OA\JsonContent(
 *              type="object", 
 *              @OA\Property(
 *                  format="string", 
 *                  default="20d338931e8d6bd9466edeba78ea7dce7c7bc01aa5cc5b4735691c50a2fe3228", 
 *                  description="token", 
 *                  property="token"
 *              )
 *          ),
 *         @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/UserResource")
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(response="401", description="fail"),
 * )
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{                

    $request->authenticate();                
  
    return response()->json(
        [ 
           "token" => $request->user()->createToken($request->email)->plainTextToken,
           "user" => $request->user();  

        ]
    );
        
    
}
```

then, when I run this command: php artisan l5-swagger:generate ,it displays this error:

> c:\myproject\vendor\zircote\swagger-php\src\Logger.php:40
> 36▕         $this->log = function ($entry, $type) {
> 37▕             if ($entry instanceof Exception) {
> 38▕                 $entry = $entry->getMessage();
> 39▕             }   ➜  40▕             trigger_error($entry, $type);
> 41▕         };
> 42▕     }

When I remove this

```
@OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/UserResource")
```

it works, but the user data is not displayed, maybe I should only return the token, and make another request with the token to get the information about the logged user. What can I do?, thanks

EDIT:

```
@OA\Response(
     *          response="200", 
     *          description="An example resource", 
     *          @OA\JsonContent(
     *              type="object", 
     *              @OA\Property(
     *                  format="string", 
     *                  default="20d338931e8d6bd9466edeba78ea7dce7c7bc01aa5cc5b4735691c50a2fe3228", 
     *                  description="token", 
     *                  property="token"
     *              ),
     *              @OA\Property(
     *                  format="application/json", 
     *                  property="user",
     *                  @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/UserResource") 
     *              )
     *          ),     
     *     )
```

I tried this, but it shows errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close except...

- use of 'format' instead of 'type'
- you do not have to specify the content type if your property is already wrapped in `@OA\JsonContent`
- you need to be careful with surplus trailing ','; doctrine can be picky with that

Here is my take which does work stand-alone (except for the missing `@OA\Info`):

```
<?php

use OpenApi\Annotations\OpenApi as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Schema
 */
class LoginRequest{}

/**
 * @OA\Schema
 */
class UserResource{}

/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 *
 *
 * @OA\Post(
 *     tags={"UnAuthorize"},
 *     path="/login",
 *     summary="User Login",
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *          @OA\MediaType(
 *              mediaType="application/json",
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  type="object",
 *                  ref="#/components/schemas/LoginRequest"
 *              )
 *          )
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *          response="200",
 *          description="An example resource",
 *          @OA\JsonContent(
 *              type="object",
 *              @OA\Property(
 *                  type="string",
 *                  default="20d338931e8d6bd9466edeba78ea7dce7c7bc01aa5cc5b4735691c50a2fe3228",
 *                  description="token",
 *                  property="token"
 *              ),
 *              @OA\Property(
 *                  property="user",
 *                  ref="#/components/schemas/UserResource"
 *              )
 *          )
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(response="401", description="fail")
 * )
 *
 */
class Controller {}
```

Comment: it works, thanks, one additional question, I am checking the swagger documentation: https://swagger.io/specification/ , but it shows specifications as json or yml files, I don't undestand, I thought that it should be something like this @OA\Response, where can I find this kind of documentation? thanks again

Comment: Good question. There are multiple things mixed here:

Comment: Swagger / OpenApi - A specification to describe your API.

OpenApi documentation tools - Tools that understands the spec file and can render it. Something like https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/, for example.

`@OA\Response`, etc. - Annotations that are processed by the L5 bundle and converted into JSON/YAML. That, in turn, is then handed over to swagger-ui to render.

The actual conversion of the annotations is done by a library called `swagger-php`.
More details: https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/

Answer (score 1):

The JsonContent you removed should be a property on the first JsonContent I think

Comment: I tried but stll not working, I edited the question

Comment: In the php-swagger docs i see they are mostly using OA/Schema in the response instead of JsonContent.